# Ruby on rails : rake aborted bad file descriptor

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have searched around, but I have not been able to find a answer that works.

I am completely new at this, so when you answer, then explain like I am a child... Or explain like I am a piece of broccoli. If you want me to install something, tell me what to write.

Well, I am trying to follow this http://guides.fatfreecrm.com/Setup-Microsoft-Windows.html and I have come to a spot where I am supposed to write 
    `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production`
and all I got was this: (I have done the "gem install mysql2" , I have installed rake as in the tutorial and have not seen any issues)

```
C:\RailsInstaller\fat_free_crm>rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production --trace   

** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create rake aborted! Bad file descriptor 
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `query'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:629:in
`configure_connecti on'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:169:in
`initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/li
b/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in
`mysql2_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in
`new_connection '
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in
`checkout_new_c onnection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in
`block (2 level s) in checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in
`loop'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in
`block in check out'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
`mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in
`checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block
in connec tion'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
`mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in
`connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in
`retrieve_conne ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in
`retri eve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in
`conne ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:83:in `rescue in create_database'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:51:in `create_database'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top
(required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top
(required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
`mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:63:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP =>
db:create
```

Comment: Did you really want the production env? (RAILS_ENV=production) ie the live site? If not then remove that bit. Then check config/database.yml and make sure you've configured the environment correctly.

Comment: Is the service of mysql up? Have you tried runnig only rake db:create ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. And I am trying this for the development mode. When I create a new application and try to execute the command, it runs successfully. But in my scenario, I have checked out the project from SVN, and trying to do rake db:migrate, and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issues and fixed it after spending two hours. May be it will help you too. 
So here are the steps, which lead me to fix the issue

1. I am assuming you are running 32 bit mysql because the problem for 64bit+32bit mysql can be something else
2. Make sure mysql.dll is compatiable with installed gem (I have mysql2)
3. To avoid issue down load it from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick
4. Copy mysql.dll to your ruby/bin

Summary: For me it was the problem of incompatibility between rails mysql2 gem and the one, which was installed on my machine