# Rails installation windows 7 bad file descriptor mysql2

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

For the past 1 day, Im trying and getting only this,

```
C:\dev\man>rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
Bad file descriptor
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/c
onnection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `query'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/c
onnection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `execute'
```

> gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.6' # is successful

What is bad file descriptor??

I followed here, [Ruby on rails : rake aborted bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168399/ruby-on-rails-rake-aborted-bad-file-descriptor) didn't work

Im very unsure about these 2 files

C:\Program Files\Mysql\Mysql Server 5.6\lib\libmysql.dll
C:\Ruby193\bin\libmysql.dll

Im on a windows 7, rails 3.2.12 and mysql 5.6, ruby 1.9.3

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I very much understood that this is a problem with 32 bit and 64 bit.

I use ubuntu 12.04. I know there is no point in using rails on windows. This has to be done for my designer to be able to view the app.

> The root of all this evil is the mysql2 0.2.6 gem. I knew, if I
>   installed mysql2 latest version this will be all good.

- I uninstalled mysql 5.6.
- Downloaded mysql 5.5.32 32-bit from
  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads Installed in
  a standard way
- Already rails 3.2.12, ruby 1.9.3 were installed in my windows 7
  system(Like in here http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html)
- Now, I carefully searched the right path where mysql server 5.5 is
  installed, It has to be here "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
  5.5\bin", but it was here "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
- How to know this, just cd to "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL
  Server 5.5\bin" and try "mysql" it should not say "command not found"
- Now, gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files
  (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program
  Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'

Thats it.

```
bundle install
rake db:migrate
```