# ERROR when type "rake db:migrate" got bad file descriptor

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, migrate

I got some trouble when migrate Mysql and Rails

Information--------------------------

> MySQL Server 5.5  (I had try MySQL Server 5.1, but not work)
>   
> Ruby 1.9.3-p429
>   
> Rails 3.2

---

I have already use

> "gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6"
>   
> "gem install mysql"

and add to gemfile

> gem 'mysql'
>   
>    gem 'mysql2','>=0.2.6'

I got error when I migrate database to MySQL

type "rake db:migrate" 

and got **Bad file descriptor**

> > C:\Sites\demo> rake db:migrate
> >     
> > rake aborted!
> >     
> > Bad file descriptor
> >     
> > Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
> >     
> > (See full trace by running task with --trace)

the detail

```
C:\Sites\demo> rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
Bad file descriptor
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `query'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `execute'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:629:in `configure_
connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:169:in `initialize
'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mi
ngw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_conn
ection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_co
nnection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checko
ut_new_connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquir
e_connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block
in checkout'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr
onize'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checko
ut'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block
in connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr
onize'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connec
tion'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrie
ve_connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/
lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:236:in `call'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:231:in `each'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:231:in `execute'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchr
onize'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `each'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rak
e/application.rb:75:in `run'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rak
e:33:in `<top (required)>'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
D:/AppServ/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

i have modify "database.yml"

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo_development
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: 'root'
  password: '1234'
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo_test
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: 'root'
  password: '1234'
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo_production
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: 'root'
  password: '1234'
```

Hoping someone could help me

I'm stock on it for several days

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try removing 'mysql' gem from gemfile, only 'mysql2' is required, after removing it do bundle install.

from the documentation of mysql on github

> To use the Active Record driver (with or without rails), all you
>   should need to do is have this gem installed and set the adapter in
>   your database.yml to "mysql2". That was easy right? :)
>
> NOTE: as of 0.3.0, and Active Record 3.1 - the Active Record adapter
>   has been pulled out of this gem and into Active Record itself. If you
>   need to use mysql2 with Rails versions < 3.1 make sure and specify gem
>   "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7" in your Gemfile

also refer this for installing issues in windows

[Rails installation windows 7 bad file descriptor mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711052/rails-installation-windows-7-bad-file-descriptor-mysql2)

Comment: @JACKLEE are you using windows?

Comment: Yes I install on Windows 8(64bit) with railsinstaller

Comment: I modify Gemfile to  gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"

Comment: @JACKLEE what is your ruby version?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3  and
Rails 3.2

Comment: @JACKLEE try removing  "~> 0.2.7" version number from the Gemfile for mysql2 gem and do 'bundle update mysql2' at the root of your application.

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell that I will come out error while typing "gem install mysql2"

Comment: But it will be ok when i use version 0.2.6

Comment: i also try "gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=D:\AppServ\mysql --with-mysql-lib=D:\AppServ\mysql\lib" this can install for 0.3.13 without error. however it will come out an error say that "Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.32 but the client library is 6.0.0."

Comment: @JACKLEE refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711052/rails-installation-windows-7-bad-file-descriptor-mysql2

Comment: "This gem was compiled for 5.5.32 but the client library is 6.0.0."  Does this means wrong on my rails file?